# Probability of two Daniels in one group

Tags: probability

my professor gave us a "fun" problem to work on at home, but I am relatively new to probability.

The question is as follows: There are four Daniels in a class of 42 students. If the class breaks into groups of three what is the probability that there is at least two Daniels in one group?

I am trying to solve the easier problem "What is the probability that there is two Daniels?" However, I am stuck even here. I will show that I have this far and why.

$$P(E)=\frac{{4 \choose 2}{40 \choose 1}}{{42\choose 3}}$$

I am using ${4 \choose 2}$ for choosing two daniels from 4, ${40 \choose 1}$, 1 student from the remaining forty, and  ${42\choose 3}$ for groups of 3 possible given 42 students. I may have a deep misunderstanding of probability, however I feel that the thing I feel most unsure about is using ${40 \choose 1}$. Part of me feels like it should be ${42 \choose 1}$, but I am not entirely sure why.

Any help, or clarifications of things I may be confused about will be greatly appreciated.

Edit after feedback: Attempted solution to original question$$P(E)=\frac{{4 \choose 2}{38 \choose 1}}{{42\choose 3}}+\frac{{4 \choose 3}}{{42\choose 3}}= \frac{29}{1435}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will assume that the question asks for the probability that there is at least one group that contains two or more Daniels.  (Note that there can be two such groups.) We will first find the probability $p$ that the four Daniels are in *different* groups. Then the answer to the question is $1-p$.

We can assume that the placement into (labelled, but it doesn't matter) groups takes place as follows. The $42$ people are lined up in a row. The first three go into Group 1, the next three into Group 2, and so on. The number of labelled groupings is then $\frac{42!}{(3!)^{14}}$, but it is convenient not to divide by the $(3!)^{14}$.

The oldest Daniel can be placed in $42$ positions, the next oldest in $39$, the next in $36$, and the next in $33$. Now the rest of the people can be lined up in the remaining slots in $38!$ ways. Thus
$$p=\frac{(42)(39)(36)(33)(38!)}{42!}.$$
The above expression for $p$ can be simplified considerably! Finally, compute $1-p$. It is $\frac{113}{410}$.

Comment: so what I did was wrong?

Comment: Apart from the typos at the bottom, $\binom{43}{x}$ instead of $\binom{42}{x}$, your answer is not wrong, it is the answer to the question what is the probability of at least twp D's in the group with label $7$, say.  I answered my interpretation of the question, which is what is the probability of at least two D's being together.  One might think that one could get from your answer to mine by multiplying yours by the number of groups, which is $14$. That's reasonable, but will not quite work, since we can (unlikely) have two D's in one group and two in another.

Comment: You will note that $14$ times your numerical answer (which uses the correct $\binom{42}{3}$ denominator) is close to mine. Mine is $113/410$, and $14$ times yours is $116/410$. The small discrepancy is due to the fact that multiplying your answer by $14$ double-counts the cases where there are two D's in one group and two in another.

Comment: I feel like I may be converging to an understanding of what is happening. However, how does mine double count the cases where there are two D's in one group?

Comment: What I was saying is that if we multiply your answer by $14$ we are double-counting some cases. For multiplying by $14$ counts twice situations in which D1 and D2 are in group 5 (say) and D3 and D4 are in group 11. That's not a problem if you are finding the probability of getting at least two D's in some **specified** group. That is what you were (correctly) finding. However, I think the question asks this: There will be trouble if two or more D's are together.  What s the probability of trouble?

Comment: Andre, you are so awesome. I know you've helped me numerous times on this website. All your answers are so concise, and seem to be filled with concern of the reader's understanding. Thank you for that. I understand what you are saying about my calculation. Now, I want to go back and understand your calculation fully.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The $P(E)$ you've calculated is correct.</s>

However, for solving the original problem, you'll have to calculate the probability of the event that there are $3$ Daniels in a group, and then add probabilities of both events.

Edit:
I re-read the problem, and your calculation seems a bit off.

For event $E$,

No of Daniels $= 4$;    ways of choosing $2$ from $4$ = $4 \choose 2$

No of "Non-Daniels" $= 42 - 4 = 38$; ways of choosing $1$ from $38$ = $38 \choose 1$.

Total groups of size $3 =$ ways of choosing $3$ from $42 =$ $42 \choose 3$

Comment: Thank you so much for answering all my questions so quickly!

Comment: @Valentino Corrected the answer.

Comment: Ahhh okay saying "non-daniels" cleared everything up for me! Thank you!!! I am cleaning up my solution now.

Comment: How does it look now? I've edited my solution.

Comment: @Valentino I haven't checked the arithmetic for the final answer, but the first part is correct.

Comment: I would interpret the question as asking for the probability that there is at least one group with at least two Daniels. Then we have the issue of double-counting the situation where there are two Daniels in two groups.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

We divide the whole class into 3 parts (14each) and now we find the probablity for one such group, that is:

P( 2 daniels in one group)= 14C2 * 28C2 / 42C4 ( here we are not concerned what happens in the other parts)
P (3daniels in one group) = 14C3 * 28C1 / 42C4
P (4 daniels in one group) = 14C4 * 28C0 / 42C4

now add up all the three for the atleast answer